# "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid", after checking that it's not DBNull

Tags: vb.net, ternary-operator, iif-function

In my ASP.Net Web-Application, I'm getting this error:

> Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

From this function:

```
Namespace atc
    Public Class Nil
        '...
        Public Shared Function Bool(ByVal Item As Object) As Boolean
            Return IIf(Item IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(Item), CBool(Item), False)
        End Function
        '...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

As you can see, I'm explicitly checking if `Item` is `DBNull`, and if it is then I return `False`.

The error does **not** occur when `Item` is **not** `DBNull`, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using `IIf` then all arguments get evaluated, no matter if the condition evaluates to true or false. In your case the function will return `false` if *Item* is *null* or *DBNull*, but `CBool(Item)` will be silently executed in the background anyway and therefore throws an exception.

In VB.NET 2008 the `If` keyword was added to provide a real ternary operator. Replace your `IIf` function call with the following:

```
Public Shared Function Bool(ByVal Item As Object) As Boolean
    Return If(Item IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(Item), CBool(Item), False)
End Function
```

Excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx):

> An `IIf` function always evaluates all three of its arguments, whereas
>   an `If` operator that has three arguments evaluates only two of them.

Comment: Wow, iff was really bad.

Comment: Although it appears to me that If has similar problems :(